# Python time and strftime

Tags: python

I am wanting to pass the current time as an object into a strftime reference. If I use:

```
d = date.fromtimestamp(time.time())

print d.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

This will print out the time, but not include the minutes/hours etc:

```
04-Jul-2014 00:00:00
```

If I try use a different call to try and get the minutes/hours:

```
d = date.fromtimestamp(time.localtime())
```

I get:

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

Both time.time() and time.localtime() appears to actually contain seconds/minutes etc, but not display them. Thoughts? gmtime also returns "AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'strftime'".

Comment: It seems `date` object is truncating the time attribute and only retaining the date. You can use `print time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
from datetime import datetime
```

not

```
from datetime import date
```

eg.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
print d.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

use `datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())` since `date.fromtimestamp(time.time())` only draws date

```
d = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
print d
print d.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
#output 04-Jul-2014 11:32:40
```